# Elasticsearch index configuration for host name

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search hosts with following requirements. For instance, I want to find all documents with `host` field:  `abc.efg.com`.

1. find hosts by partial host name, eg: `dfg`, or `dfg.com`
2. find hosts by whole host name, eg: `abc.efg.com`

How should I create an Index using DSL for these requirements?